# How to hide output of subprocess in Python without preventing other subprocesses from running

Tags: python, subprocess

I run Python 3.3.5 on Windows, and a very basic version of something I'm working on looks like this:

```
import os
import subprocess
import time
path = r"C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\Tor_Browser\Browser\firefox.exe {0}"
url = "http://google.com"
views = 5
opened = 0
for i in range(views):
    subprocess.Popen(path.format(url))
    time.sleep(15)
    opened = opened + 1
    print ("Times opened:", opened)
    os.system("taskkill /f /im firefox.exe")
```

What this code is supposed to do is run my firefox/tor browser with the google url 5 times for 15 seconds each and then close it.
It does just this, however, I can't seem to stop the terminal from displaying the text: "SUCCESS: The process "firefox.exe" with PID xxxx has been terminated."

I've tried changing the line

```
os.system("taskkill /f /im firefox.exe")
```

to

```
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')    
subprocess.Popen("taskkill /f /im firefox.exe", stdout=FNULL)
```

but when I do the program only opens the browser once, closes it and then ceases to open it again but still displays the "Times opened" text.

Anyone have any ideas as to how I can stop the terminal from displaying this text?

Thanks

-Luke

Comment: Can you route STDERR to FNULL as well? It seems weird that SUCCESS would be written to err, but we're on windows so who knows

Comment: @a-p Just tried adding stderr=FNULL but with the same result, the browser opens once, closes it and then ceases to open it again but the "Times opened" text continues to display

Comment: When I try this it with `stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w')`, I don't get the output you're seeing. I'm on 2.7 so maybe that's the difference?

Comment: @a-p that might be the difference, I'll give this a try with 2.7

Comment: Another (better) way to do this is, since you have firefox Popened already, just bind that pipe to a name and then send it a `.terminate()`

Comment: unrelated: use `subprocess.DEVNULL` instead of `FNULL` on Python 3 e.g., `subprocess.check_call("taskkill /f /im firefox.exe", stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)` (note: unlike `Popen()`; `check_call()` waits for `taskkill` to finish)

Comment: @j-f-sebastian Thanks, I might give this a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
import subprocess
import time
path = r"C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\Tor_Browser\Browser\firefox.exe {0}"
url = "http://google.com"
views = 5
opened = 0
for i in range(views):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(path.format(url))   # Change here to bind pipe to a name
    time.sleep(15)
    opened = opened + 1
    print ("Times opened:", opened)
    proc.terminate()                            # send process term signal
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help, I really thought I'd hit a dead-end there...

Comment: Yeah no worries, my earlier comments totally tunnel vision'd on the taskill stuff, missed the obvious solution /sigh -- glad it's working tho

Comment: Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @Luke25361: add `proc.wait()` after `proc.terminate()` to avoid spawning the next `firefox` process before the previous one has finished. `with subprocess.Popen(..) as proc: .. proc.kill()` will do it automatically.

Comment: @j-f-sebastian Thanks, I'll definitely try this